# t4 template error occurs from powershell not visual studio

Tags: c#, powershell, t4

I'm attempting to use powershell to process a .tt file. I think it's really close but I get an error invoking from powershell that's not present when using visual studio.

**Powershell script**

```
function DoThing
{

  $inputfile = 'D:\source\62\test.tt'

  [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating") | Out-Null
  [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('D:\source\62\Builder.dll') | out-null  

  $host = New-Object ("CustomHost.CustomCmdLineHost") 
  // impl ITextTemplatingEngineHost


  $server = New-Object ("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine") 

  $server.ProcessTemplate($inputfile, $host);

}
```

**Simple.tt template**

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>

This content was generated from a template
in the year <#= DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() #>
```

When run from Visual Studio,  the .tt generates the file fine

However from powershell I recieve an unhelpful 'ErrorGeneratingOutput'

I think the gist of the issue is how to implement a ITextTemplatingEngineHost when used from powershell, welcome any suggestions here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can wait till someone provides you suggestions on how to use Microsoft's T4 engine, but personally speaking, I prefer to use Mono's open source implementation directly,

https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/main/src/addins/TextTemplating

Compiling Mono.TextTemplating and TextTransform you get a command line utility TextTransform.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think the t4 side of things is fine as in the template runs fine in one host but not the other. A command line app works fine with the same ITextTemplatingEngineHost dll so it seems possible there is a way.